# iOS utility application-flipside view settings

Tags: ios, settings, uisegmentedcontrol

I am making a utility application, and I have a label on my main view. Depending on the user's selection, that label should say one of two things. How can I use a segmented control to change the label text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your flipside, create an IBAction called `segmentedControlChanged` - and hook it up to the 'value changed' trigger on the segmented control.

At the top of your settings controller, declare this constant:

```
#define kSegmentKey @"SegmentSetting" // Call these whatever you want
```

In your `segmentedControlChanged` method, write to NSUserDefaults, like so:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:[sender selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:kSegmentKey];
}
```

In your main view controller's `viewWillAppear`, put the following code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int setting = [defaults integerForKey:kSegmentKey];
    if (setting == 0) {
        myLabel.text = @"First Message";
    }
    else {
        myLabel.text = @"Second Message";
    }
}
```

Comment: viewWillAppear? do you mean viewDidLoad? because just doing what you said, nothing happens if I change the selection on the flipside view

Comment: no, viewWillAppear - because the view may be kept in memory when you flip back your view (try logging something in viewDidLoad and see if it appears when you flip back your view)

Comment: well, by default, the application does not have a viewWillAppear method. So, do I need to call it? If so, where?

Comment: all view controllers have viewWillAppear - you just need to implement it. after your viewDidLoad in your main controller start typing - (void)viewWill... and it will show you the method!

Comment: alright. that function is being called. but i added NSLogs that say which segment is highlighted, and no matter what, it says 1, and the text is never changed

Comment: In which case, try logging what [sender selectedSegmentIndex] is in your action method, then see what happens when you change the segment

Answer (score 0):

You can:

(1) store the segmented control's value in a variable that's passed as a return value to the `FlipsideViewControllerDidFinish` method, or else

(2) store the value in some area accessible to both the `Flipside` view and the `First` view, such as `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.